# Pass a macro as parameter to package xsim

Tags: expl3, xparse, xsim

I am trying to write a document using the xsim package. It is divided into chapters and each contains its own exercises and its solutions, at the end of each.

At present, the structure of each chapter is written by hand as in `ChManual.tex` but I would like to use something like `macroChapter.tex`, which uses `\thechapter` as parameter to invoke and print the collections defined for xsim.

The following MWE works if you use `ChManual.tex`, if you uncomment the lines `%\input{macroChapter.tex}` of chapters 1 and 2, it does not work showing an error: `unknown-collection "collCh\thechapter"`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{xsim}

\DeclareExerciseCollection{collCh1}
\DeclareExerciseCollection{collCh2}
\DeclareExerciseCollection{collChManual}

\begin{filecontents}{Ch1.tex}

    \begin{exercise}
    This is exercise 1 from chapter \thechapter.
    \end{exercise}

    \begin{solution}
    This is solution of exercise 1 from chapter \thechapter.
    \end{solution}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Ch2.tex}

    \begin{exercise}
    This is exercise 1 from chapter \thechapter.
    \end{exercise}

    \begin{solution}
    This is solution of exercise 1 from chapter \thechapter.
    \end{solution}

    \begin{exercise}
    This is exercise 2 from chapter \thechapter.
    \end{exercise}

    \begin{solution}
    This is solution of exercise 2 from chapter \thechapter.
    \end{solution}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{ChManual.tex}

    \begin{exercise}
    This is exercise 1 from chapter \thechapter (Manual).
    \end{exercise}

    \begin{solution}
    This is solution of exercise 1 from chapter \thechapter (Manual).
    \end{solution}

    \begin{exercise}
    This is exercise 2 from chapter \thechapter (Manual).
    \end{exercise}

    \begin{solution}
    This is solution of exercise 2 from chapter \thechapter (Manual).
    \end{solution}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{macroChapter.tex}

    This is chapter \thechapter.

    \collectexercises{collCh\thechapter}

    \input{Ch\thechapter.tex}

    \collectexercisesstop{collCh\thechapter}

    \printcollection[print=exercises]{collCh\thechapter}

    Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.

    \printsolutions[chapter=\thechapter,collection=collCh\thechapter]

\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{manualChapter.tex}

    This is chapter Manual.

    \collectexercises{collChManual}

    \input{ChManual.tex}

    \collectexercisesstop{collChManual}

    \printcollection[print=exercises]{collChManual}

    Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.

    \printsolutions[chapter=3,collection=collChManual]

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}

%\input{macroChapter.tex}

\chapter{Two}

%\input{macroChapter.tex}

\chapter{Manual}

\input{manualChapter.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, make the example into a single file: the fact you're using `\input` is irrelevant.

Comment: When using input I only wanted to show and justify the need for the content of the `macroChapter.tex` file (included multiple times in main doc) to be completely parametric in function of the macro `\thechapter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is yet another variant of “expand the argument before you pass it to the next macro”.

Specifically you want `x` variants of the macros `\xsim_start_collection:n`, `\xsim_stop_collection:n` and `\xsim_print_collection:nn` as well as adapted user commands:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand \collectexercises {t!m}
  {
    \IfBooleanTF {#1}
      { \xsim_start_collection:x {#2} }
      { \xsim_start_collection:n {#2} }
  }

\RenewDocumentCommand \collectexercisesstop {t!m}
  {
    \IfBooleanTF {#1}
      { \xsim_stop_collection:x {#2} }
      { \xsim_stop_collection:n {#2} }
  }

\RenewDocumentCommand \printcollection {t!O{}m}
  {
    \IfBooleanTF {#1}
      { \xsim_print_collection:nx {#2} {#3} }
      { \xsim_print_collection:nn {#2} {#3} }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \xsim_start_collection:n  {x}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \xsim_stop_collection:n   {x}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \xsim_print_collection:nn {nx}

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Then use (notice the exclamation marks):

```
\begin{filecontents}{macroChapter.tex}

    This is chapter \thechapter.

    \collectexercises!{collCh\thechapter}

    \input{Ch\thechapter.tex}

    \collectexercisesstop!{collCh\thechapter}

    \printcollection![print=exercises]{collCh\thechapter}

    Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.

    \printsolutions[chapter=\thechapter,collection=collCh\thechapter]

\end{filecontents}
```

[image]

BTW: I'd rather use `\arabic{chapter}` instead of the `\thechapter` in the collection names – you want the number and not the printed output!

Comment: Thanks a lot, but `\printsolutions` is missing.

Comment: @Fernando I only did quick checks but I don't think a patch is needed for it.

Comment: It is needed. Your solution does not work for me because `\printsolutions` generates the same error. I tried myself but I can't find the key.

Comment: @FernandoNadal What I did was: add the patches to your MWE: it ran without errors and produced the picture I attached. But anyway, the patch is completely analoguous: you need the variant `\xsim_print_all_solutions_per_type:nx` of `\xsim_print_all_solutions_per_type:nn`. Check the definition of `\printsolutions` in `xsim.interface.code.tex`.

Comment: Sorry, sorry, sorry !! My mistake. in my document, I added `!` to all the comands, including `\printsolutions`.